# Underline long url

Tags: css

On mobile devices with a width < 400px underlined links with long text breaks in two lines and just the second line will be underline.

How can i solve this problem.

CSS code:

```
a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;  
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    bottom: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 5px);
    min-height: 2px;
    height: .15em;
    background: #1a1a1a;
    transition: all .15s cubic-bezier(.25,.46,.45,.94);
} 

a:hover:after {
    width: 105%; 
}
```

Comment: Um, `text-decoration: underline` instead of that `:after` thing? Or if you did that only to control the height of the underline, use `border-bottom`.

Answer (score 1):

With this you have removed the text underline

```
text-decoration: none;
```

And then you replace it with a line in a a:after, this is how this is expected to work and if you want to revert it remove the text-decoration and a:after block.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you converted `<a>` to inline block element. just remove that `display: inline-block;` applied to `<a>` and it will work.

By default `<a>` tags are inline elements. So there is no need of applying `display: inline-block` for . But in case from some where `<a>` tag is inheriting some other display properties, the you have to apply/overwrite `display: inline` to your `<a>` element.

Comment: I thought so, too. But the real problem is, that he rolls his own underlining implementation with the `:after` selector.

Comment: it didn't help.

Comment: As @Boldewyn mentioned, if you are trying for a custom underline, my answer will not work. But if you are okay to use with default text underline, it will work. Please let me know if you want a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Allthough I would recommend using the text-decoration property as mentioned in previous answers, you may wrap the links content in an inline element and apply some margin/padding to use the border bottom property. Then you may animate the underline in one or more lines.

```css
div {
  width: 210px;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

span {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #1a1a1a;
  transition: all .15s cubic-bezier(.25, .46, .45, .94);
}

a:hover span {
  margin: 0 -10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-bottom-color: navy;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#"><span>Short link</span></a>

  <a href="#"><span>Really long link text here that breaks into 2 lines</span></a>
</div>
```